# declare a view height dynamically

Tags: android

my xml is below in xml we have declare a view height how we declare view height in dynamically.

```
    </TableRow>
    <View android:layout_height="1dip" android:background="#FF909090" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to give you view and android:id field like

```
</TableRow>
<View android:id="@+id/someidvalue" 
  android:layout_height="1dip"
  android:background="#FF909090" />
```

Then, in your activity, you'll need to use the method .

```
View myView = (View)findViewById(R.id.someidvalue)
```

Then use either setMinimumHeight (which I think may be what you are looking for) or setLayoutParams to modify how your View is displayed

```
myView.setMinimumHeight(height) 
myView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParam(width, height))
```

where height and width some values you'd like the view to have for height and width